# Multiple Parameter Classes in Python

Tags: python, class, polynomial-math

I have a parent equation, for which some values need to be calculated first. For instance:

```
parent = child1*1 + child2*2 ...
```

However, each child needs to be flexible in calculating it's value based on a parameter that can change. I was thinking that a class might be the way to do this in Python, however I'm not familiar with how to effectively do this.

So, the meat of the question, how do I write a class to accept multiple parameters to be used with an fsolve later on? Something like this?

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.child1 = 1*x + 2*x ...
        self.child2 = x**2 + x**3 ...

print(parent.child1(500) + parent.child2(1000))
```

Edit for Clarification:

Alright, I was trying to keep this generalized, but I guess my specific problem might be instructive. I'm attempting to calculate the temperature at combustion of some fuels. As a first pass, I need to figured out the differences in enthalpies of Ideal Gas approximations. These enthalpies are calculated of the form:

'H° − H°298.15= A*t + B*t2/2 + C*t3/3 + D*t4/4 − E/t + F − H'

where A, B, C, etc. are specific numeric values. However, if I change the component, e.g. I have to figure out both O2 and N2, then N2 has different values for A, B, C than O2. I was attempting to use these components as the children, i.e.:

'self.N2 = A1*t ...'
'self.O2 + A2*t ...'

and the parent equation would be of the form:

'0 = h.N2(t) + h.O2(t) + other stuff'

The fsolve comes in because I need to find out what 't' equals, but I need to evaulate 't' at the parent class level.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here. Can you give some clearer examples with expected input/output. What will the ``500`` and `1000` be used for here?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I write a class to accept multiple parameters to be used with an fsolve later on"?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're looking for `numpy.poly1d`.  That provides a much more robust polynomial class than you could really hope to implement yourself ...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use methods like this:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self, x):
       self.__child1 = 1*x
       self.__child2 = 2*x

    def child1(x):
        return self.__child1*x

    def child2(x):
        return self.__child2*x
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't do anything close to what I think you'll expect.

What you need is multiple parameters.

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.child1 = 1*x1 + 2*x1 ...
        self.child2 = x2**2 + x2**3 ...

>> x = parent(500,1000)
>> print(x.child1+x.child2)
987638461
```

Although you'd be better off with a simple function rather than a class...

```
def poly_wants_a_cracker(x1,x2):
    child1 = 1*x1 + 2*x1 ...
    child2 = x2**2 + x2**3 ...
    return child1 + child2

>>poly_wants_a_cracker(500,1000)
987638461
```

Where 987638461 is your answer depending on whatever it is you're actually doing